# PHP 5.3.8, JSON & CentOS 6

Tags: php, json, apache, centos, centos6

We're running CentOS 6 and PHP 5.3.8 (as an apache module) which should have JSON as part of it's core (I'm told).  Looking at `# php -i` on the command line I can see under Configure Command `'--enable-json=shared'` ... great!

However, looking at php_info() on a web page Configure Command shows `'--disable-json'`.

No problem I thought, I'll just install it using pecl:

```
# yum update php
# yum install php-pear
# yum install gcc
# pecl install json
# service httpd restart
```

Success, that aught to do it I thought.  However php -m shows:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/json.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/json.so: undefined symbol:                                                                 ZVAL_DELREF in Unknown on line 0

Apologies if this is a silly question but does anyone know what's going on here and could you point me in the right direction on how to fix this so that JSON starts working?

Many thanks

Comment: Have you considered recompiling PHP with JSON enabled? That doesn't make much sense to be disabled explicitly as it is a core module.

Comment: Hello Rudi, so is the command line PHP different to mod_php?  Both appear to be running the same version of PHP although one has --enable-json=shared and the other --disable-json.  

Not sure what that means.  I haven't recompiled PHP before and I don't want to break anything (it's a live server).  Is recompiling easy if I just want to remove the '--disable-json' flag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thought I'd follow up with the solution.  The PECL installation seemed to conflict with PHP 5.3.8 so after a bit of research and some advice I toyed with the idea of:

```
# yum remove php
# yum install php
```

However, after further advice instead went with:

```
# yumdownloader php-common
# rpm -Uvh --force php-common*.rpm
# service httpd reload
# rm php-common*.rpm
```

This did the trick and JSON is now working again.  Hope this helps someone else.

Thanks

Comment: this did work. yay. but i neede to 
#pecl install json
and then uncomment 
the extension in php.d/json.ini

Answer (score 2):

download `json-1.2.1.tgz` FROM PECL

```
enter code heretar zxvf json-1.2.1.tgz
cd json-1.2.1
vi JSON_parser.c
```

Find `ZVAL_DELREF` replace to `Z_DELREF_P`
(You can Find in 3 place)
And Save file

Then

```
phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

You can get your json.so
don't forget add to php.ini

Comment: There is also `function_entry` you have to change to `zend_function_entry` in file `json.c`. [Package php5-json breaks firephp](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87067/package-php5-json-breaks-firephp)

Answer (score 1):

1. Login to SSH
2. Make tmp and var/tmp exec
   `mount -v -o remount,exec /tmp`
   `mount -v -o remount,exec /var/tmp`
3. No go ahead and install JSON
   `pecl install json`
4. And finally, make tmp and var/tmp noexec again
   `mount -v -o remount,noexec /tmp`
   `mount -v -o remount,noexec /var/tmp`

Comment: SSH into what? Given the context of the question, this answer makes little sense.

Comment: Agree with Axle, this makes very little sense. Why need to mount? What is being mounted?